# How to take the element from menu dropdown in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website of SAP. My automation task is to click tools from top menu and the drop down appears and I have to choose User-Defined Windows from the drop down and another menu appears from which i have to choose NSC_USER_OPTIONS (fourth from the bottom of the menu). How can i choose these element?

The ID of element is `m_4864` and i cannot inspect the element of `User-Defined Windows` and `NSC_USER_OPTIONS` because as soon as I click on inspect the menu disappears

to click tools at the top menu my code is

```
class NavSetPageModel
    {
        public NavSetPageModel()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(StaticDriver.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "m_4864")]
        public IWebElement tools { get; set; }

        public void MenuBar()
        {
            tools.Click();
        }


    }
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution :

```
  [FindsBy(How = How.xpath, Using = "//*[contains(text(),'User-Defined Windows')]")]
    public IWebElement element { get; set; }

  [FindsBy(How = How.xpath, Using = "//*[contains(text(),'NSC_USER_OPTIONS - NavSol User Optiions')]")]
    public IWebElement subElement { get; set; }

 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);             
 builder.MoveToElement(element).MoveToElement(subElement).Click().Build().Perform();
```